# Symfony2 Relationship entities + forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, relationship

I'm trying to write one form for submitting against MySQL DB, but I can't get it working, I've tried a lot of things (separate forms, create an `->add('foo', new foo())` to a field, and trying to parse plain SQL with a normal HTML form is my only solution, which is obviously not the best.

This is my DB structure:

![enter image description here][1]

As you can see I need to insert the `comments` textarea to `ticketcomments` among the user who wrote it, etc.

On `crmentity` the `description` field.

Then on `ticketcf` the fields that I need to submit from form, are this (because you wont know if I don't tell you because of the field names):

```
tcf.cf594 AS Type,
tcf.cf675 AS Suscription,
tcf.cf770 AS ID_PRODUCT,
tcf.cf746 AS NotificationDate,
tcf.cf747 AS ResponseDate,
tcf.cf748 AS ResolutionDate,
```

And, of course, every table needs to have the same `ticketid` **id** for the submitted form, so we can retrieve it with one simple query.

It will be easy to do with plain SQL instead of using DQL and Symfony2 forms, but is not a good way to do it.

**EDIT**
This is my new created entity `Ticket.php`, which has relations to the tables above... if someone could check it out and tell me if it's okay...

**ticket.php**

```
<?php 
namespace WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VtigerTicketcomments
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vtiger_troubletickets")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\TicketsRepository")
 */

class Tickets
{
    /**
     * @var \WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\VtigerCrmentity
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\VtigerCrmentity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticketid", referencedColumnName="crmid", unique=true)
     * })
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ticket_no", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $ticketNo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="groupname", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $groupName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VtigerContactdetails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="contactid", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $parentId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VtigerAssets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="assetsid", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="priority", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $priority;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="severity", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $severity;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="solution", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $solution;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_log", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updateLog;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $versionId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hours", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $hours;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="days", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $days;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="from_portal", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fromPortal;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VtigerTicketcomments", mappedBy="ticketid")
     * 
     */
    protected $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VtigerTicketcf", mappedBy="id")
     */
    protected $ticketcf;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VtigerCrmentity", mappedBy="crmid")
     */
    protected $crmtable;
}
```

**VtigerTicketcf.php**

```
<?php

namespace WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VtigerTicketcf
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vtiger_ticketcf")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class VtigerTicketcf
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_546", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf546;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_556", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf556;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_589", type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf589;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_590", type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf590;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_592", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf592;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_593", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf593;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_594", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf594;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_675", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf675;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_689", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf689;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_690", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf690;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_691", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf691;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_693", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf693;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_746", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf746;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_747", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf747;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_748", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf748;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_761", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf761;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_763", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf763;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_764", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf764;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_765", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf765;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cf_770", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cf770;

    /**
     * @var \WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\Tickets
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\Tickets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticketid", referencedColumnName="ticketid", unique=true)
     * })
     * 
     */
    private $id;
}
```

**VtigerTicketcomments.php**

```
<?php

namespace WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VtigerTicketcomments
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vtiger_ticketcomments")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class VtigerTicketcomments
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comments", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ownerid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $ownerid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ownertype", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ownertype;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdtime;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commentid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\Tickets
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity\Tickets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticketid", referencedColumnName="ticketid", unique=true)
     * })
     * 
     */
    private $ticketid;
}
```

**VtigerCrmentity.php**

```
<?php

namespace WbsGo\clientsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VtigerCrmentity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vtiger_crmentity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class VtigerCrmentity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="smcreatorid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $smcreatorid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="smownerid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $smownerid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modifiedby", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $modifiedby;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="setype", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $setype;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdtime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modifiedtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $modifiedtime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="viewedtime", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $viewedtime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="presence", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $presence;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="crmid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $crmid;

}
```

**And this is my repository method...**

```
public function findByIdAndCustomerId($id) {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                        '
                        SELECT 
                        IDENTITY(t.id) AS id,
                        t.ticketNo AS Ticket,
                        t.title AS Asunto,
                        t.status AS Estado,
                        t.updateLog AS LOG,
                        t.hours AS Horas,
                        t.solution AS Solucion,
                        t.priority AS Prioridad,
                        tcf.cf748 AS F_Reso,
                        tcf.cf747 AS F_Resp,
                        tcf.cf746 AS F_Noti,
                        tcf.cf770 AS IDPROD,
                        tcf.cf594 AS Tipo,
                        tcf.cf675 AS Suscripcion,
                        c.comments AS Comments,
                        CONCAT (CONCAT(s.firstname, \' \'), s.lastname) AS Contacto
                        FROM WbsGoclientsBundle:Tickets t
                        JOIN t.parentId s
                        JOIN t.ticketcf tcf
                        JOIN t.comments c
                        WHERE  t.ticketNo = :ticketNo

        ')
        ->setParameter('ticketNo', $id)
        ;

        try {
            //return $query->getSingleResult();
            return $query->getResult();
        }
        catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I can retrieve an array of X ticket even if I just search by ONE ID, because if ID1 has 4comments, then I got 4 same tickets, one per comment... How can I make it only ONE ticket with `comments => array(...)` so I can iterate inside that `comments` array inside twig?

And also `VtigerCrmentity.Description` doesn't work either, it returns this error...

> Notice: Undefined index: crmid in
>   /var/www/wbsgo/dev.wbsgo/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php
>   line 826

I don't have getter and setter because I'm re-generating them again, if annotation are OK, the entities will update correctly with get/set and my forms will be able to submit using relationships, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to do it, and the problems.

The relations are this:

`crmentity.id` > Main, this table has **not** relationships

`troubleticket.ticketid` > This one has relation with `crmentity.id`

`ticketcf.ticketid` > this one has relation with `troubleticket.ticketid`

So the order when you insert needs to be `crmentity`->`troubleticket`->`ticketcf`

But in Symfony2, when you make forms, you must create the last table element as the first form to be generated, so I'll post my code in case someone has the same problem as me.

http://pastebin.com/wLPyXvbj

:)

Answer (score 1):

You may embed a form that does represent an underlying entity field by setting `mapped` option to false, e.g.:

```
->add('comments', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => new VtigerTicketcommentsType(),
    'mapped' => false
))
```

However, be careful when assigning form data, since `$form->submit($data)` will not set data to underlying collection of comment objects. You'll need to process them manually inside the controller. You may access the data that has been flagged as non-mapped using `$form->getExtraData()` after the data is submitted to the form.

If you'd like Symfony to automatically set data to comments, you'll need to construct a relationship between `VtigerTroubletickets` and `VtigerTicketcomments` entities, which, according to the question title, you don't have and try to avoid.

**Edit:**

A form type is bound to a given entity class. By default, each field you add to a form type must have an underlying property in a declared entity class (or getter/setter pair if property is not defined public). When you construct a form object from form type (`OpenTicketType`) and data (`new VtigerTroubletickets()`):

```
$form = $this->createForm(new OpenTicketType(), new VtigerTroubletickets());
```

the form get bounds with data present in the object you just created. The object does not have comments property, even more, the form itself knows the field is not mapped and it will not try to populate it from the object, so naturally the collection is rendered as empty, as no data about comments was passed.

To get past this, you may pass array of data instead of newly created object (note: the values may be empty, however comments array must have length > 0 - the comment has to exist, though without actual data).

```
[
  "title"    => "...",
  "priority" => "...",
  "solution" => "...",
  "comments" => [
    0 => [/* comment 0 data */],
    1 => [/* comment 1 data */],
    .......
  ]
]
```

This is the form creation. When the form is POST-ed, there is one additional step beside constructing the form. The request data has to be bound onto form, so you do `$form->submit($request)`. Now the form AND underlying entity object will get populated with fresh data.

The `$form->getExtraData()` is simply a method for accessing the data that form holds and is not mapped to an underlying object - which comments field is, since we flagged it as such.

Alternatively to using `getExtraData` - extracting data from form manually - you may add a property `comments` to `VtigerTroubletickets` entity with getters/setters and not mark it as a db column. That way, you may remove the `mapped => false` option at form type, and form will automatically read/populate comments property. 
Still, when persisting, these comments will not be considered for storing, so you'll have to handle them manually. Likewise, when fetching an object from database, the comments property would be empty, so prior to creating a form, you'd have to add some comments to an object, e.g.:

```
$tickets = new VtigerTroubletickets();
$tickets->setComments(....);
$form = $this->createForm(new OpenTicketType(), $tickets);
```

Comment: Exactly, I don't have it and I try to avoid because the DB is used by another platform so I don't want to change anything to avoid conflicts. The way you are saying (using `collection`) I don't see anything rendered, the only way I actually get it working is using `->add('comment',
     new VtigerTicketcommentsType()
   )` this way everything renders good, but I don't know how it will work when I press submit, you mentioned `$form->getExtraData()` but how exactly this works in my case? Also, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain more where you say `To get past this, you may pass array of data instead of newly created object`? I don't understand what you say about `comments array must have length > 0 - the comment has to exist, though without actual data).`

Comment: What I meant is that you were getting nothing rendered when using "collection" because none of the comments existed when form was constructed. In order to get them rendered, you have to add at least one comment to the entity or form (depends on whether you chose to map data from entity to form or not).

Comment: I'm trying to do what you are saying but I'm getting this error `Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?` doing this `$entity = new Tickets();
        $entity->setTicketcf(new VtigerTicketcf());
        $form   = $this->createForm(new TicketsType(), $entity);`

Answer (score 1):

I think @usoban has taken you most of the way.  Think of these as two long comments as opposed to answers.

It seems you have a ticket entity and a comment entity with a 1 to many relationship between them but you don't want to actually establish a formal relationship between them because the "DB is used by another platform"?  What exactly does that mean.  Are you sharing php code with another application?  Are you using doctrine 2?  With Doctrine 2 you can establish the relationship without changing the actual database.

You really should look at adding a getComments to your ticket entity.  It will make your S2 life much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't want to change the DB because I'm using vTiger CRM, and then this other app using S2 with the same database (so no PHP is shared, ONLY the DB) Actually, as you can see there are more than just `comments` table, if I could make relationship for the diagram I've posted that'll be great but I'm a bit lost on how to make everything work, I've never used S2 before so I'm a newbie on here... Reading a lot of documentation 'n stuff...

Answer (score 1):

This answer is built on what @usoban said about using an array but takes a slightly different approach.

```
// In the controller
$formData = array();
$formData['ticket'] = new Ticket(),
$formData['comments'] = array(new Comment(), new Comment());

$form = $this->createForm(new TicketCommentsType(), $formData);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) 
{ 
    $formData = $form->getData();
    $ticket   = $formData['ticket'];
    $comments = $formData['comments'];

    // Persist ticket

    // Persist comments
```

TicketCommentsFormType simply brings the two different entities into one form.

```
class TicketCommentsFormType

public function buildForm(

    $builder->add('ticket',new OpenTicketType());
    $builder->add('comments','collection',array(
            'type' => new VtigerTicketcommentsType()
```

With this approach there is no need to have any direct relation between Ticket and Comment.

Comment: I assume that `controller` part is for once the form has been submitted and not for the creation itself?

Comment: I've changed my whole code trying to use relationships without updating the DB (so only with Doctrine) but I think something is wrong...